# Reverse doubly linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

Are there any corner cases missing here?

```
class Node
{
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node prev;
}

Node reverseDLL(Node head) 
{
    if(head == null || head.next == null)
       return head;

    Node previousNode = head.prev;
    Node currentNode = head;
    Node nextNode; 

    while(currentNode!=null)
    {
       nextNode = currentNode.next;

       currentNode.next = previousNode;
       currentNode.prev = nextNode;

       previousNode = currentNode;
       currentNode = nextNode;
    }

    head = previousNode;
    return  head;
}
```

Comment: Write unit tests and find out.

Comment: There is a (slightly) simpler approach. Each node in your doubly linked list has references to the previous and next nodes, so all you really have to do is travel to each node in the list and swap them. The only tricky part is that after the swap, you need to use the node's `prev` to get to what's (in your view) the next node.

Comment: This question lacks context how the nodes are linked. Is the list circular or not?

Comment: For us to be able to review this it would help to see the add node, insert node, delete node and the forward traverse methods as well as the reverse method.

Comment: This is probably a doubly-linked-list, but we need more information about your specification to be of proper help.

Answer (score 1):

If we are allowed to pass the tail node to the reversal method (**`Node reverseDLL(Node head, Node tail)`**), we can perform the reversal by reversing the data integer fields instead of restructuring the list. All in all, I had this in mind:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node prev;

    Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public class ReverseDLL {

    static void reverseDLL2(Node head, Node tail) {
        Node left = head; 
        Node right = tail;

        while (true) {
            if (left == right) {
                return;
            }

            int tmp = left.data;
            left.data = right.data;
            right.data = tmp;

            if (left.next == right) {
                return;
            }

            left = left.next;
            right = right.prev;
        }
    }

    static void printList(Node head) {
        for (Node current = head; current != null; current = current.next) {
            System.out.print(current.data);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            nodes.add(new Node(i));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
            nodes.get(i).next = nodes.get(i + 1);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
            nodes.get(i).prev = nodes.get(i - 1);
        }

        printList(nodes.get(0));
        reverseDLL2(nodes.get(0), nodes.get(9));
        System.out.println();
        printList(nodes.get(0));
        reverseDLL2(null, null);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This works fine if you have simple data types as the payload, but if you have more complex objects in there, depending on the case you may need to build a copy function, maybe end up using more memory and of course more code = higher chance of bugs. Also, it would be nice to check for circular lists.

Comment: @ChatterOne Not true. In Java, we deal with references to objects, and not objects themselves, so the reversal operation would be the same since we simply swap references.

Comment: You're right, I'm digging too much into Python these days, I guess